# Kafka producer and consumer in seperate EC2 instance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have 2 ec2 instances one for Kafka broker and the other for Kafka Consumer. May i know how to connect both the ec2 instance to communicate with each other. If i produce a message in my broker i need to get it in the consumer.

Basically, i am looking for that part of configuration where i need to give the consumer information in the broker ec2 instance and vice versa (whichever way it works) . Do i need to use some api or something ?

I have tried in a single node cluster and it worked.

Comment: You are trying to access from Java or manually from console?

Comment: You could improve your question by showing exactly what you've tried on a single node that works, and the error that you get when trying it across two nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter you are hosting your broker in ec-2 or elsewhere as long as it is accessible to consumer.

A sample consumer in Java using StringDeserializer for both key and value. You need to use the KafkaConsumer API if you are accessing from a Java program

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "YOUR_KAFKA_BROKER_ADDRESS");
 props.put("group.id", "test");
 props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
 props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
 props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
 consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
 while (true) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
         System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
 }
```

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kafka across machines, you need to configure the listeners correctly. This article explains how: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 0):

> where i need to give the consumer information in the broker

Brokers don't push messages to consumers, so you wouldn't give the information for the consumer to any broker

Any code that works against a single broker should work for more than one, assuming network settings are configured properly